# put and get Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

How to get the value that i put in Broadcast Receiver? 
Please help me

In my Activity

```
public static void startActivity(Context context) {
   //what can i put here?
}
```

In Intent Service

```
intent.putExtra("DriversID", 1351351);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

my Broadcast Reciver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String DriversID = null;
    if (bundle != null) {
        DriversID = bundle.getString("DriversID");
        Toast.makeText(context, "DriversID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("getDriversID", DriversID);
    context.startActivity(i);


    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
     }
}
```

here is the exact scenario , when the GCM notify me i will get the message from inten  and post it to broadcast and then  activity will get the value of message , how about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReciever in your activity:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        // String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        // do other stuff here
    }
};
```

You then should register in your activiy (in onResume for example):

```
this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("unique_name"));
```

And remember to unregiester (here in onPause, choose whatever fits your needs):

```
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

To send the data you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("unique_name");

    // put whatever data you want to send, if any
    // intent.putExtra("message", "some data");

    // send broadcast
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: ah Sir I'm little bit confuse, can u show me exact what will i put?

Comment: The send part is in your Gcm BroadcastReceiver, and the recieve in your activity

Answer (score 0):

This will do.
    Set an action for intent and send broadcast.

```
intent.setAction(action);
```

and check for the action in receiver to find the intent

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(action))
    String DriversID = intent.getStringExtra("DriversID");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and how about how to get Broadcast driver id and send it to Activity ?

Comment: I already update my question and sadly im still not get it :(

Comment: here is the exact scenario , when the GCM notify me i will get the message from inten  and post it to broadcast and then  activity will get the value of message , how about that ?